# MDB/ODBC with PHP - wrong/grouped query result

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a problem with my odbc-connection over PHP. There is a database called statistics.mdb where several information are stored in. In this database there are two tables: 
 - Turnover EShop
 - Shops

The Table "Shops" is much smaller than "Turnover EShop". The following connection/query works without any problem with the table "Shops". But it shows an issue when I try to use it with "Turnover EShop".

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=O:\\Statistics\\statistics.mdb;Uid=Admin");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Turnover EShop WHERE ProductGroup = 'A22'"; 
$exec = $pdo->query($sql);

foreach ($exec as $row) { echo $row[1]."<br>"; //index Problem mentioned below: 1 = 'ProductName' }
```

There are results, even the correct ones. But the table "Turnover EShop" looks like this (simplyfied 3 rows):

```
OrderID: 1
ProductName: Super Product 77
ProductNo: 123-456
ProductGroup: A22

OrderID: 2
ProductName: Super Product 77
ProductNo: 123-456
ProductGroup: A22

OrderID: 3
ProductName: Product 12
ProductNo: 888-999
ProductGroup: B52
```

Finally, the result is: Super Product 77 (Just once...) But it should be there twice...

Another funny thing is, by using `$row['ProductName']`, it just works for the table "Shops". In the bigger table "Turnover EShop" there's an error caused by an undefined index... So I had to use numbers which not match with the numbers of the columns.

```
foreach ($exec as $row) { echo $row[1]."<br>"; }
```

Thanks for your support in advance and wish you a great day

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

The problem was so simple to solve... *shame*

There is another Table called "Turnover". So, the "SELECT * FROM Turnover ... EShop" took the data out from the table "Turnover" instead of "Turnover EShop"... So I had to use [ ] around the table name.

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM [Turnover EShop] WHERE ProductGroup = 'A22'";
```

So I can be productive now ;-) THX

Comment: Absolutely, in MS Access field and table names with space or special characters or reserved words should be enclosed with square brackets. Also, PHP arrays are zero-based, so first column, *OrderID*, would be `$row[0]` and second column, *ProductName*, would be `$row[1]`.